# Agregate the output of multiple projects in visual studio into a single folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution with several related console applications. All of the applications are meant to be distributed to the same machine, and they all have some common dependencies. This is akin to what I have:

```
Solution
  - ConsoleApp1
    - source code
    - dependency1
    - dependency2
  - ConsoleApp2
    - source code
    - dependency1
    - dependency3
```

When I build, I get something like this:

```
Solution
  - ConsoleApp1
    - source code
    - dependency1
    - dependency2
    - bin
      - ConsoleApp1.exe
      - dependency1
      - dependency2
  - ConsoleApp2
    - source code
    - dependency1
    - dependency3
    - bin
      - ConsoleApp2.exe
      - dependency1
      - dependency3
```

Instead, what I want is:

```
- CommonDir
    - bin
      - ConsoleApp1.exe
      - ConsoleApp2.exe
      - dependency1
      - dependency1
      - dependency3
```

I tried creating an empty project that references the other projects, however, this did not yield the expected results. I know I can just create a script that uses dotnet to build each of the executables, and copies the files however I want. However, I imagine there must be a "proper" way to do this.

The project contains C# applications.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I posted an answer, you can take a look. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since VS use MSBuild to build the C# projects in the solution one by one, you need to modify the contents of each .csproj.

Like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>C:\CommonDir\bin\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
</Project>
```

And after you build the entire solution:

[image]